# Is there an analytics framework or service for OSX applications?

Tags: macos, analytics

For iOS there are companies such as Flurry that give you analytics for your apps. Is there such a thing for OSX apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using Deskmetrics ([www.deskmetrics.com](http://deskmetrics.com)) and i love the product. 
Deskmetrics offers custom events, hardware and OS analysis, and funnel analytics.

*Disclosure - I'm on the company advisory board.

Comment: it's pretty expensive to have more than 1 application. Maybe you should offer something cheaper. Actually, I see the pro version is only for 2 applications. Very expensive